# Angular HttpClient authenticate on API using token

Tags: angular, api, jenkins, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to get my data from my Jenkins JSON - API using HTTPClient. Because the data, I want to access is restricted I need to authenticate against Jenkins. So I generated an API-Token. Now I want to Authenticate myself using the Angular HTTPClient, but I don't know how.

Can anybody help me with my problem?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) to append additional headers on every outgoing http requests.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OutgoingInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {



  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

     interceptedRequest = req.clone({
         setHeaders: {

             // These headers is for Passport authentication.
             // You might to change these headers as you need
             // Also you need to store your token in localStorage etc.

             Accept: 'application/json',
             Authorization: tokenData
         }
     });

     return next.handle(interceptedRequest);
  }
}
```

And you need to add this newly created interceptor to your module's provider array:

```
providers: [

    ... 

    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
]
```